# yield and CSS not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: css, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and currently installed Laravel 5.2. I tried to create a layout with laravel and linked the local bootstrap file. But it's not getting linked.

My bootstrap.css is stored in `authentication\public\assets\css\bootstrap.min.css` and `authentication\public\assets\css\navbar-static-top.css`

Here is my code:

```
<title>Laravel Social and Email Authentication</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/navbar-static-top.css')}}">

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


@yield('head')


    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Social Authentication</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">

@yield('content')

</div> <!-- /container -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<!--{!! HTML::script('/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: here is the output screen]

Comment: Providing a screenshot to debug HTML is not relevant: please provide produced HTML source code instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make sure your template file is saved with `blade.php` extension and you should make sure it's correctly processed by PHP. At the moment it seems it's displayed as ordinary text file,so any Laravel/PHP functions won't work in it